# How to handle large store in redux when it use with react?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm curious to know, how to manage the redux-react store when it grows with thousands of thousands component. Because there is only one global redux store we can use in react. When the number of components increases with the application, it can cause to reduce the performance largely.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49586234/is-it-a-good-idea-to-keep-huge-data-object-in-a-single-store-of-redux your question os answered here

Comment: As I understood in there, it's about how to make it smaller and optimal. but not about what should do after it increases certain size.

Comment: You refactor it and make it smaller. Break your components into further hierarchy and add reducer for each as mentioned in the link above. Thanks

Comment: @Rohitha you should split your reducers and avoid nesting your state as it will become harder to update as your app grows. follow this doc https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers there is a great explanation for your case